# Accessing my application from AWS-S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded files for my application to my S3 buckets in AWS. It's a movie search app. For some reason, the page loads up with the proper CSS, but I'm unable to get the search functionality to work. It works well on my local environment but not in AWS. Also, I've uploaded application files before into AWS and they all worked just fine. I'm not sure what is wrong this time.

Here's one of the webpages

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Movie Info</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href='index.html'>MovieInfo</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="movie" class="well"></div>
    </div>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>  <script rel="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script>getMovie();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the second webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Movie Info</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href='index.html'>MovieInfo</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class='jumbotron'>
            <h3 class="text-center">Search For Any Movie</h3>
            <form id="searchForm">
                <input type="text" class='form-control' id='searchText' placeholder="Search Movie">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="movies" class="row"></div>
    </div>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>  <script rel="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the css script

```
#movies img, #movie img{
    width:100%;
}

@media(min-width:960px){
    #movies .col-md-3 .well{
    height:390px;
    }

    #movies .col-md-3 img{
    height: 240px;
    }
}
```

Here's the js script

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $('#searchForm').on('submit',(e)=>{
        let searchText = $('#searchText').val();
        getMovies(searchText);
        e.preventDefault();
    })
})

function getMovies(searchText){
    axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchText}&apikey=94d282a9`).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response)
        let movies = response.data.Search;
        let output = '';
        $.each(movies, (index, movie)=>{
            output += `
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="well text-center">
                        <img src="${movie.Poster}">
                        <h5>${movie.Title}</h5>
                        <a onclick="movieSelected('${movie.imdbID}')" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Movie Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            `;
        })

        $('#movies').html(output);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
   //console.log(searchText);
}

function movieSelected(id){
    sessionStorage.setItem('movieId', id);
    window.location = 'movie.html';
    return false;
}

function getMovie(){
    let movieId = sessionStorage.getItem('movieId');

    axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${movieId}&apikey=94d282a9`).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response)
        let movie = response.data;
        let output = `
            <div class='row'>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="${movie.Poster}" class="thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h2>${movie.Title}</h2>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Genre: </strong>${movie.Genre}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Released: </strong>${movie.Released}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Rated: </strong>${movie.Rated}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>IMDB Rating: </strong>${movie.imdbRating}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Director: </strong>${movie.Director}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Writer: </strong>${movie.Writer}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Actors: </strong>${movie.Actors}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="well">
                    <h3>Plot</h3>
                    ${movie.Plot}
                    <hr>
                    <a href="http://imdb.com/title/${movie.imdbID}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">View IMDB</a>
                    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-info">Go back to search</a>
            </div>  
        `;

        $('#movie').html(output);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

I granted public to each individual object, and the encompassing object also has public access.

Comment: Any error message in browser's dev tool?

Comment: Probably CORS. Enable that on your API GW if you are using that. If you aren't using APIGW consider it.

Comment: Frank, I actually realised that I was using http instead of https request and it did say that in the error messages. I need to pay more attention. I changed the request type and it worked. Thanks for the hint.